# Get Azure Blob data in JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code to obtain the list of blobs (uploaded files) of my blob container (named `id`):

```
app.controller("attachmentsController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    var ct = this;

    $scope.go = function () {
        ct.id = $scope.id;

        var rootUrl = 'https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net';
        var containerPropertiesUrl = `${rootUrl}/${ct.id}?restype=container`;
        var blobListUrl = `${containerPropertiesUrl}&comp=list`;
        // get container's blob list
        $http.get(blobListUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                ct.blobs = response.data;
            });
    };
}]);
```

In the `response.data` I obtain XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ContainerName="https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/000002">
<Blobs>
<Blob>
<Name>logo-separator.svg</Name>
<Url>https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/000002/logo-separator.svg</Url>
<Properties>
<Last-Modified>Fri, 25 Aug 2017 10:00:01 GMT</Last-Modified>
<Etag>0x8Y4EBAX0D5850C7</Etag><Content-Length>2048</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type><Content-Encoding />
<Content-Language />
<Content-MD5>BDm9NV0Zn4e6zQO2e/D1Dg==</Content-MD5><Cache-Control />
<BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
<LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
</Properties>
</Blob>
</Blobs>
<NextMarker />
</EnumerationResults>"
```

Is there a way to get all this in the JSON format, in order to be able to use it in my angular application?

Comment: try changing url to this : var blobListUrl = `${containerPropertiesUrl}&comp=list&jsoncallback=?`;

Comment: I edited the OP to explain that I don't read a blob content, but I read the list of blobs (files in my case) from a given container

Comment: Is there still no way to get a response in json?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the latest Azure **List Blobs** REST API response format (last updated 23 August 2017), the `response body is in XML format`.

You will need to implement custom function or use some npm package such as [xmltojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmltojson) for converting the response body from XML to JSON format.

Reference:

[Azure List Blobs REST Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#response)

Answer (score 0):

My (temp?) solution as for now is to use a custom function that transforms XML in JSON:

```
app.controller("attachmentsController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    var ct = this;
    // Changes XML to JSON
    ct.xmlToJson = function(xml) {

        // Create the return object
        var obj = {};

        if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
            // do attributes
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
                obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
            obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }

        // do children
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    obj[nodeName] = ct.xmlToJson(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = obj[nodeName];
                        obj[nodeName] = [];
                        obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    obj[nodeName].push(ct.xmlToJson(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };

    $scope.go = function () {
        ct.id = $scope.id;

        var rootUrl = 'https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net';
        var containerPropertiesUrl = `${rootUrl}/${ct.id}?restype=container`;
        var blobListUrl = `${containerPropertiesUrl}&comp=list`;
        // get all possible values
        $http.get(blobListUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                var xmlString = response.data;
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
                var myObj = ct.xmlToJson(xml);
                ct.blobs = myObj.Blobs;
            });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but here's what i did...

I already had Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer installed on my mac. All files were uploaded already - basically just select all, right click and Copy - create a new .json file and paste! just tidy the code and you're good to go.

```
{
    "CloudHub.Azure.Storage.Blobs": 
    {
            "connectionString": "BlobEndpoint=https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net;SharedAccessSignature=....",
            "containerName": "mycontainer",
            "accountUri": "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net",
            "sourceFolder": "",
            "items": [{
              "relativePath": "Image1.JPG",
              "snapshot": ""
            }, {
              "relativePath": "Image2.JPG",
              "snapshot": ""
            }, {
              "relativePath": "Image3.JPG",
              "snapshot": ""
            }],
            "sasToken": "SAS-TOKEN....."
          }
        }
```

This isn't a good solution for pulling dynamic blob list. My requirement was to pull a list of all photos I had uploaded in the container and I just needed the relative paths.

Cheers..